# How do you manage virtual environments made by PyCharm after installing Conda?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I installed Anaconda last night. Previously, I was using `pip` and the virtual environment GUI in PyCharm to setup and manage my virtual environments.

Now I know I can create  a new environment in my project structure by navigating to the project then using

`conda create --prefix ./myenv mypackage1 mypackag2`

That's really cool. But how do I deal with the fact that PyCharm has already created a virtual environment using `virtualenv`? And for older projects that I'm still working on, how do I transition from using conda to manage those project environments (also made by PyCharm and populated with pip)?

For example:

1. How do I use conda to install `hub` inside a pre-existing non-conda
   environment?
2. How do I even call conda from an activated non-conda environment,
   since when I try it doesn't register conda's existence?

Note: PyCharm just calls `virtualenv` to create a virtual environment. This question is not about PyCharm.

Comment: Have you checked the PyCharm documentation? _How do I use conda to install hub inside a pre-existing non-conda environment?_ Is that related to the PyCharm issue? _How do I even call conda from an activated non-conda environment, since when I try it doesn't register conda's existence?_ What do you mean, how would that work?

Comment: PyCharm does not manage virtual environments. It simply calls `virtualenv` and/or `pip` on project start-up and when installing new packages, just as a user would from the command line. This question has nothing to do with PyCharm, except for that tangential piece of information.

Comment: Alright, I had misinterpreted what you wrote. Can you expand on question/example 1?